# MVC routing controller and action are reserved keywords

Tags: asp.net-mvc-routing

In MVC routing are controller and action reserved keyword?
I mean if I define routes like below, is the system going to break?
If it breaks then why?

```
routes.MapRoute(name: "MyRoute", url: "{cont}/{act}", defaults: new { cont = "home", act = "index" });
```

or

```
routes.MapRoute(name: "MyRoute", url: "{a}/{b}", defaults: new { a= "home", b= "index" });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. Controller and action in asp.net routing are reserved keywords. See this (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/routing?view=aspnetcore-3.0#reserved-routing-names)